# I made level system in roblox studio, script seems to be ok, but instead of leveling up after xp hits max, it just continues going, what should i do?

Tags: lua, roblox

so script is supposed to be working, everything works except it after exp hits the needed amount it wont level up, it just continues going, here is script: I apologize for bad english

```
local maxXp = 20
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local levelinfo = Instance.new("Folder")
    levelinfo.Name = "LevelsInfo"
    levelinfo.Parent = player
    
    local level = Instance.new("IntValue")
    level.Name = "Level"
    level.Value = 1
    level.Parent = levelinfo
    
    local exp = Instance.new("IntValue")
    exp.Name = "Experience"
    exp.Value = 5
    exp.Parent = levelinfo
    
    
    local xpNeeded = Instance.new("IntValue")
    xpNeeded.Name = "expNeeded"
    xpNeeded.Value = 20
    xpNeeded.Parent = levelinfo
    
    
    exp.Changed:Connect(function(newExp)
        if exp.Value >= xpNeeded.Value then
            level.Value += 1
            exp.Value -= xpNeeded.Value
            xpNeeded.Value = xpNeeded.Value + 2
        end
    end)    
end)
```

the part which supposedly should be working is this:

```
    exp.Changed:Connect(function(newExp)
        if exp.Value >= xpNeeded.Value then
            level.Value += 1
            exp.Value -= xpNeeded.Value
            xpNeeded.Value = xpNeeded.Value + 2
        end
    end)
```

I get no errors and nothing seems to be wrong with it, can someone tell me what to do?

Comment: which code modify (add experience) to the `exp` variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, issue turned out to be that I was incerasing my exp from localscript and it was not replicated to server, I fixed issue and now everything works fine

Comment: Turns out there was no problem in this script, it was just that when exp was incerased from localscript I forgot that it would not be replicated to server so game could not notice it, I made xp incerasing serverscript and it works well now

Comment: Btw thanks for taking your time answering here.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code and it worked well. Place a script(not a local script) in the ServerScriptService and it is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Place a script(not a local script) in the `ServerScriptService` and it is going to work.